# Angular 5 - Refresh Current Tab?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

The way my project is set up, a listener in one of my tabs causes the whole tab to refresh which causes it to be updated with the first tab's information, until I click off of it onto another tab and navigate back to the current tab.

1) Is there a way to simply refresh to current tab?
2) Out of curiousity, is there a way to find the index of the currently selected tab?
3) Also out of curiosity, is there a way to navigate to a specific tab?

And is it just me or do the [Angular Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api) not list all the methods [available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugef9.jpg) for MatTab?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `MatTabGroup`? https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup

It has a `selectedIndex` property for the index of the active tab.

Comment: I'm using `@ViewChildren(MatTabGroup) tabGrp: QueryList<MatTabGroup>;` but It's [still not showing up](https://imgur.com/a/lcwIK)